# Digital Ocean App: How to set environment variables for Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I have a Spring Boot app which is deployed by a Dockerfile to Digital Ocean Apps. When I want to set the environment variables (like spring.datasource.url) I get the following error: "Can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores". How can I set the varaibles with this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the following error: "Can only contain alphanumeric characters
> and underscores".
> Blockquote

It's likely that this error message means that the environment variable name (you're trying to set) contains special characters (that are not allowed in environment variable names).

> How can I set the varaibles with this restriction?

In your Spring Boot app, you can set environment variables  using different approaches:

1. You can set environment variables (that will be available to your Spring Boot app) in your Dockerfile
   For example:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ENV SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
COPY target/test-app.jar /test-app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/test-app.jar"]
```

2. You can set environment variables for your app in your Digital Ocean Apps configuration by navigating to your app's settings in the Digital Ocean Apps dashboard and adding them in the "Environment Variables" section.

For example:

```
name: my-app
services:
  - name: web
    command: java -jar test-app.jar
    envs:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb
```

3. You can use base64 encoding

Use base64 encoding: If you need to include non-alphanumeric characters in your environment variables, you could encode the value in base64.

For example:
You have the environment variable `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL`.

1. Set the encoded value `aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwL2VtYWlsL2VtYWlsLnBocD9wYWdlPTE` to `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` instead of the actual value `http://localhost:8080/email/email.php?page=1`.
2. Then you can decode the value.